# How to convert BigQuery data to custom type?

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Does anybody know how to convert `Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryResults` to a custom type? As far as I see the `BigQueryClient` type doesn't have generic versions of `ExecuteQuery` and `ExecuteQueryAsync`.

According to Google BigQuery quickstart guide we can do something like that:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public string FirstValue { get; set; }

        public string SecondValue { get; set; }

        public string ThirdValue { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetQueryResult()
    {
        var queryExecutionResult = client.ExecuteQuery(Query, null);

        foreach (var row in queryExecutionResult)
        {
            yield return new Foo
            {
                FirstValue = row["column1"],
                SecondValue = row["column2"],
                ThirdValue = row["column3"]
            };
        }
    }
```

I have implemented my custom converter which uses reflection under the hood. I don't quite like a reflection. So perhaps somebody knows some better way. I put my implementation below.

```
    public class Foo
    {
        // I use custom attribute which is similar to DescriptionAttribute.
        [BigQueryColumnName("column1")]
        public string FirstValue { get; set; }

        [BigQueryColumnName("column2")]
        public string SecondValue { get; set; }

        [BigQueryColumnName("column3")]
        public string ThirdValue { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetQueryResult()
    {
        var queryExecutionResult = client.ExecuteQuery(Query, null);

        return queryExecutionResult.Select(bigQueryRowToFooConverter.ConvertToFoo);
    }

    public Foo ConvertToFoo(BigQueryRow row)
    {
        var item = new Foo();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(Foo).GetProperties())
        {
            var attribute = (BigQueryColumnNameAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propertyInfo, typeof(BigQueryColumnNameAttribute));
            var value = row[attribute.ColumnName];
            propertyInfo.SetValue(item, value);
        }

        return item;
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks good. I don't know a  better way than it yourselves, like you did!

Comment: We don't support custom serialization or deserialization. (That's ended up being quite a lot of the code in the Firestore client... it gets complex really, really quickly.) If your approach meets your needs, I'd stick with it. If there are things we could provide in `BigQueryRow` to make that simpler, I'd be happy to consider them - I'd suggest filing an issue at https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues. (To reiterate, not for "support custom types" but "make it easier for customers to support custom types themselves".)